# Voltage regulator output too high

Tags: power-supply, voltage, voltage-regulator

I'm trying to provide a 3.3V source for my micro controller from a 5V power supply, however seem to be having issues with all the 3.3V regulators I've tried.

I'm currently trying to use an MT1117-3.3, datasheet [here](http://www.matrix-microtech.com.tw/imgs/PDF/Products/Bipolar_LDO/MT1117_V1.03.pdf).

When I turn on my 5V supply, the output I get from the regulator is 4.1V and 4.5V if I remove the load.

I tried an L78L, which gives a similar result althoguh apparently this requires 5.3V to regulate.

I've also tried an LM2931A which also gives a similar result although it's input voltage requirement is less than 5v.

Would appreciate any suggestions on what might be the problem. Diagram below.

[image: Test circuit diagram]

Comment: If that is your load, it might be too low. Can you add at least 5mA of load (e.g. 470 ohms resistor) to check the output voltage?

Comment: I've increased the load by reducing to first 500 ohms, and then 333ohms, in both cases the resulting voltage was still around 4.1V. Current through the resistor is around 4.2mA and 6.3mA respectively.

Comment: Your numbers don't add up. For example, 4.1/500 would result into 8.2mA of current, not 4.2mA. And 500*4.2 would be 2.1V, not 4.1V. Please describe your circuit in detail, and describe what are you measuring from where and how, because the measurements make no sense.

Comment: What does your 5V supply measure with the same voltmeter?

Comment: Output of LDO in some condition start oscillating. It may cause the high voltage you measured. Oscilloscope will help. Choose proper capacitor is important. Check datasheet.

Comment: The LED reduces the voltage across the resistor. The voltage on the LED is just over 2V, this conforms to kirchoffs law.

Comment: I have 10uF caps as recommended by the data sheet. If there is oscillation it's way above hthe KHz range as the output is flat on my improvised arduino oscilloscope.

Comment: @Geoff - Adding photos of your h/w setup (both closeups of the board and wider angles showing wiring etc.) might help. Sometimes members here see things in photos which are problematic, but which weren't obvious to ask about - until they see the photos! Click to Edit the question, then hit Ctrl+G on a a PC (or click the "mountains" icon above the edit box), then you can insert an image < 2MB in size. Resize if necessary beforehand. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- The L78LXX requires 2 volts difference between input and output.  5V in to a 3.3V regulator is outside of the specifications.  It's anybody's guess what it will do.
- The MT1117A datasheet specifies a tantalum capacitor on the output.  If you use anything else, there's a good chance it will oscillate.  The output voltage may appear to be too high or too low when it oscillates - it depends on what your voltmeter does when hit with something it doesn't expect.
- The LM2931 requires a 100µF capacitor to be stable - your 10µF won't be enough.  On top of that, the [LM2931 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2931-n.pdf) says that it requires that the capacitor have a specific equivalent series resistance (ESR) to be stable.  If your capacitor is too small or if it doesn't meet the ESR requirements given in figure 34 on page 10, then it will oscillate - that causes the same wonky voltages readings that you would see if the MT1117 were oscillating.
- Check that you have the regulator connected the right way around.  It was really easy to connect regulators in TO-92 or TO-220 housings backwards.  It's harder with SMD components, but it still happens.
- Outside of those causes, you should check to see if your voltmeter is working correctly.  Many voltmeters show incorrect voltages when the battery is weak.

Check things in this order:

1. Check the battery in the voltmeter - or check if it reads a known voltage correctly.
2. Make sure the regulator is wired correctly.
3. Double check the output capacitor type and value.
4. Hook the output to an oscilloscope and see if it is oscillating.

Comment: I've cross checked the voltages against multiple sources so fairly sure it's not the multimeter. Also checked the wiring. I used my arduino as a makeshift scope and got no oscillation, although it could still be at very high frequency.

Sounds like the most likely cause is the caps, so I'll go over those. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the specification of datasheet you attached,
the load current in your circuit seems to be too low.
Recommended is a minimum load current of 5 mA.
The load in your circuit is about 3mA or less.
Try to decrease the resistor value of about 470ohms.

Comment: I've increased the load to above 5mA and still getting a voltage of around 4.1V out.

Comment: Have you already doublechecked the correct pinning of the regulator in your circuit ?

Comment: I've checked and rechecked the wiring - yes it can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide a 3.3V you can just use a zener diode :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQfURX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

with Vzbk < 5*RL/(R1+RL)

Comment: That'll give you 3.3V, but is it really a good solution?  3.3V Zener diodes aren't really precise.  R1 will constantly waste a lot of power and it limits the current available to the load.  A regulator is the correct solution.  Geoff is trying to use a regulator, but there's something wrong with the circuit involved.  Suggesting a worse solution isn't much of an improvement.

Comment: If the Rs is sufficiently high it is independent of input voltage.

Comment: The regulation of the Zener depends on the current through it - that determines Rs.  If Rs is too high, then the Zener current will be too low and it won't regulate properly.  Also, if Rs is too high, the microcontroller won't get enough current to operate.

Comment: Yeah but for a  big range of resistor values of R1 it regulates just fine.Look in my projects which are not very professional a zener diode is just a fine regulator.For example if you increase 500Ohms Rs for a range of resistance values the load voltage barely changes.

Comment: 1. It "works" if you don't care if 3.3V is 3.3V or higher. 2. It "works" if you don't mind wasting energy all the time.  3.  It "works" if you don't need high current. Rs of 500 ohms means you can get only a few milliamperes to the microcontroller.  To get more current, you need a small Rs - which also wastes more power.

Comment: I can't "look in your projects."

Comment: The difference in output voltage for different resistances is so small in the order of mV.

Comment: The 1N4733A is a 5.1V Zener diode.  Maybe you meant the 1N4728A instead?

Comment: Yes I meant 1N4728A.

Comment: [Crash course in the problems of Zener regulators.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/109674/zener-diode-as-voltage-regulator)

Comment: @JRE Thank you for persuading me to study harder zener diodes:)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the right zener on hand. Furthermore, given the micro controller, I'd like a regulated supply since they can be quite sensitive to over voltage.